# Boot Camp on Late 2010 Macbook Air using USB flash drive?

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro

I want to dual-boot via boot camp to install XP on an external USB flash drive on my Late 2010 Macbook Air.  Has anyone done this successfully?

Virtualization is not an option, installing XP on small internal partition and putting programs on USB drive is not an option, looking for a real solution only

(Important detail - I have a Macbook Pro that I can use to get things rolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootcamp is a tool for installing Windows on the same drive with your OS X.

If you want to have Windows on a USB, then boot from your Windows installation cd and install Windows on the USB.

Then whenever you want to boot into Windows, plug your USB, hit alt/option and select Windows as your boot disc.

It may be better though, if you find a ready/made Windows USB Edition.

Either way, it will work :)

Edit:

After your first boot into Windows, do not forget to insert the Mac OS X Installation disc, in order to install the Windows/Bootcamp drivers!

Comment: Genius thought on finding a readymade Windows USB installation, because that's going to save me a huge amount of headache.